# Grouping listings in an object by attribute

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, object

I have an object that looks like this:

```
[ 
    {
        NAME: 'Mich',
        Age: 52,
        Member: false
    },
    {
        NAME: 'Sarah',
        Age: 21,
        Member: true
    },
    {
        NAME: 'Sarah',
        Age: 90,
        Member: false
    }
]
```

I'd like to group them by their *Name* attribute in the following way:

```
{
    "Sarah":
    [
        {
            NAME: 'Sarah',
            Age: 21,
            Member: true
        },
        {
            NAME: 'Sarah',
            Age: 90,
            Member: false
        }

    ],
    "Mich":
    [
        {
            NAME: 'Mich',
            Age: 52,
            Member: false
        }
    ]
}
```

I've tried to make an algorithm but I failed. Note that there is no pre-defined name list (names can be random). If you have an idea how to achieve this please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
let d = [
  {
    NAME: 'Mich',
    Age: 52,
    Member: false
  },
  {
    NAME: 'Sarah',
    Age: 21,
    Member: true
  },
  {
    NAME: 'Sarah',
    Age: 90,
    Member: false
  }
];
let group = d.reduce((r, a) => {
  r[a.NAME] = [...r[a.NAME] || [], a];
  return r;
}, {});
console.log(group);
```

Comment: This solution is unnecessarily O(n^2), due to building a new array of length O(n) on each iteration.

Answer (score 1):

For each object, create an array for that name if it doesn't already exist, and push the object to the array:

```js
var byName = {};

people.forEach(person => {
    var name = person.NAME;
    if(!byName[name]) { byName[name] = []; }
    byName[name].push(person);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try for below code:

```
var finalObj = {};
    arr.forEach(function(element){
        if(Object.keys(finalObj).includes(element.NAME)){
            finalObj[element.NAME].push(element)
        } else {
            finalObj[element.NAME] = [element];
        }
    });
    console.log("fff", finalObj);
```

Comment: This solution is unnecessarily O(n^2), by using Array.includes on an array of length O(n) on each iteration. You can test whether the object's key exists in O(1) by other means.